# C# JWT Protection against Timing attack necessary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, jwt

I am currently implementing a REST API which uses a JWT for authentication and authorization.

I read about [Timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) and was wondering if it would make sense to implement protection against such attacks?

My implementation (to protect against such attacks) would just assure that the time, the endpoint takes to generate the JWT (for login), is always 1000ms.

Comment: Why? Wich protection? What is the question?

Comment: As I said in the question "I read about Timing attacks and was wondering if it would make sense to implement protection against such attacks?"

Comment: Sure, but how? S.O. is not for recommendations, instead fix and debugging code. I wont vote down but yes vote to close because is not the question you should ask here.

Comment: Stackoverflow was made to ask technical questions. This is a technical question about whether a protection algorithm against Hash Timing attacks should be used.

Comment: At some point you have to compare some string/array to some string/array. This is where timing attacks can occure. This might include JWT verification, depending on the chosen algorithm. And so, yes, you should have a protection against it. And no, you shouldn't implement it by yourself.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for the answer, if I should not implement it myself, is there a native support for that? I do not want to install some Nuget package, only if it is trustworthy.

Comment: There is a package from Microsoft for JWT: [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)

Comment: @trauni there is no "native" support. Someone has to implement it. But it is better for people with experience in cybersecurity to do that, timing attacks is just one of many cybersecurity threats. I guess, at the end of the day you have trust someone. It is likely better to trust some library (with good opinion) rather than implement it by yourself. For example 1000ms delay on every JWT creation sounds like insanely bad performance and UX. And, more importantly, timing attacks may occure on JWT verification as well. You now have bad UX, with bad protection. Use a library.

Comment: You have to do some work, some research, tries, etc. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I did my research, I even implemented my very simple protection and now I was asking if it was necessary to invest more time to implement such protection properly.

Comment: I'm sure you did. You should ask about the code you want to implement, or if you need a suggestion, you should ask it in another stackexchange like https://security.stackexchange.com/ not here in S.O.